# Fill GridView with Data from 2 Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp.net project and 2 tables:

### Regitrations

RegisterID
EventID
UserID
DateTime

### User

UserID
Username

Now I want to have a gridview with shown the DateTime and Username.

I try this since 2 hours but cant get an single chance to show this.

How to do?

Until now I have this:

```
        public static List<EventRegistration> GetAllRegistrationsForEventID(Guid eventID)
    {
        using (CyberDBDataContext db = new CyberDBDataContext())
        {
            DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();

            options.LoadWith<EventRegistration>(p => p.CyberUser);
            db.LoadOptions = options;

            List<EventRegistration> list = (from a in db.EventRegistrations where a.EventID == eventID select a).ToList();
            return list;
        }
```

And this:

```
             <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllRegistrationsForEventID"
        TypeName="DAL.RegistrationHandler">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DbType="Guid" DefaultValue="0000-000000-000000-0000" Name="eventID"
                QueryStringField="id" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
        EmptyDataText="Keine Spieler registriert" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RegisterID" HeaderText="RegisterID" SortExpression="RegisterID"
                Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EventID" HeaderText="EventID" SortExpression="EventID"
                Visible="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Name' ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign='Center'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Timestamp" HeaderText="Anmeldezeit" SortExpression="Timestamp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID"  />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Your select method is the `GetAllRegistrationsForEventID` which returns a List of EventRegistration.

Return an anonymous object which project the Events and the User information together, like:
First have a class:

```
class AllInfo
{
    string RegisterID ;
    string EventID ;
    string UserID ;
    string DateTime;
    string Username;
}
```

then

```
public static List<AllInfo> yourMethodName(Guid eventID)
{
    using (CyberDBDataContext db = new CyberDBDataContext())
    {
        DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();

        options.LoadWith<EventRegistration>(p => p.CyberUser);
        db.LoadOptions = options;

        List<AllInfo> list = (from a in db.EventRegistrations 
                             where a.EventID == eventID 
                             select new AllInfo (){ RegisterID = a.RegisterID, 
                                                    EventID = a.EventID,
                                                    UserID = a.UserID,
                                                    UserName = a.User.UserName...}).ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

}